# android.widget.Toolbar cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar even though that is not the case

Tags: android, androidx

Im not sure why i am getting this error. 
I am not casting from two different toolbars

Here is my code:

```
androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar toolbar = (androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_header);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
```

What am i doing wrong here.

Here is the error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.mycontactlist, PID: 12667
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mycontactlist/com.example.mycontactlist.ContactListActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Toolbar cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
```

Comment: Can you include the XML where you define the `toolbar_header`?

Answer (score 5):

Wrong Toolbar class defined in your xml file. Change it from

```
<Toolbar .../>
```

to

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar .../>
```

Answer (score 4):

In your XML, you probably declared your toolbar using just `<Toolbar></Toolbar>` in that case, the toolbar will be created from the package `android.widget`. So if you try to call `findViewById` by casting it to `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar` it will surely throw you a RuntimeException.

If you are using AndroidX, which you should, then you have to change the xml declaration of your toolbar to `<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar></androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>`

You can then proceed to call your `(androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar) findViewByid(..)` which should succeed