# android.widget.Toolbar cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar (android toolbar)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-toolbar, android-constraintlayout

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.sitamadex11.gcectapp

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var toggle: ActionBarDrawerToggle

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)


        val drawerLayout=findViewById<View>(R.id.drawerLayout) as DrawerLayout

        toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout ,toolbar,R.string.open,R.string.close)
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
        toggle.syncState()

        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

        val navView=findViewById<View>(R.id.navView) as NavigationView

        navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener{
            when(it.itemId){
                R.id.nav_home -> Toast.makeText(applicationContext,
                    "Clicked Home",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                R.id.nav_aboutus -> Toast.makeText(applicationContext,
                    "Clicked About Us",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                R.id.nav_acad -> Toast.makeText(applicationContext,
                    "Clicked Academics",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            }
            true
        }

    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

        if(toggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
            return true
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Toolbar

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:title="GCECT"
            android:background="@color/teal_200"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ACTIVITY"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_drawer_menu"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

logcat error message:

```
2021-12-06 17:41:58.372 3377-3377/com.sitamadex11.gcectapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sitamadex11.gcectapp, PID: 3377
    java.lang.RuntimeException:**Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sitamadex11.gcectapp/com.sitamadex11.gcectapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Toolbar cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar**
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Toolbar cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        at com.sitamadex11.gcectapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:23)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7994)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7978)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
```

How to solve the issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [android.widget.Toolbar cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar even though that is not the case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60346281/android-widget-toolbar-cannot-be-cast-to-androidx-appcompat-widget-toolbar-even)

Answer (score 1):

This error is happening because your XML is using the base android `Toolbar` but your code is importing the AndroidX `Toolbar`

You can change your xml as follows:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
```

Instead of:

```
<Toolbar
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. issue solved